# Can I cache an entire MongoDB collection in memory for improving query performance?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection which has some thousands of complex document objects. When I run a query which has some more than 10 - 15 find conditions of nested and deeply nested values, it takes around 20-30 ms to yield the result. I was googling about improving query speed and I came to know there is a way to store entire collection in memory.

> Can somebody please through some light over how to keep entire
>   collection cached in memory?

I don't wanna lose my on-disk collection, I just want to have my entire collection to be available in memory and I'm planning to update in memory collection every few minutes from my on-disk collection.

**NOTE**: I don't wanna use the only in-memory collection, I want to preserve my ability to have persistent data

Comment: You can deploy a replica set with in-memory and wiredTiger b-tree instances. For example an in-memory primary and on-disk secondary, or the opposite. It depends what exactly you want to achieve. In-memory engine is available in MongoDB Enterprise and in "percona server for mongodb"

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what storage engine you are using, with MMAPv1 you can load the data and indexes into memory you can run the touch command:

```
db.runCommand({ touch: "collection", data: true, index: true })
```

More info can be found here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/touch/

However, if you're using WiredTiger storage enginer you can just write a simple query either to hit all the indexes:

```
db.collection.find({indexedField: 1}).count()
```

or load documents in memory with a find:

```
db.collection.find({documentsIWant: true})
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin Smith for answer, I'm using WiredTiger storage engine but heating both the queries that you mentioned for wiredTiger didn't do anything